# Dynamically update data on webapp without refresh

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have created a webapp that was working fine as a standalone app without the need of nodejs or anything, but now I am trying to migrate it to Expressjs/nodejs.

The problem that I am having right now, is that I want to be updating the data on that website dynamically, in realtime without the user having to refresh the webpage. The webpage is basically just showing some values, and they need to refresh every half a second or every second to make it appear realtime.

First I started off with EJS, but I couldnt find a way to do this with EJS and most answers that I found pointed out that I have to use something like socketIO to get this done and so I did.

My socketIO code on the server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  setTimeout(function() {emiter(socket)}, 1000)
  console.log('a user connected');
});

function emiter (socket) {
  socket.emit('MyEvent', GetData.RData.R[" 1"].Val);
}
```

My socketIO code on the front end:

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.2:3000')

  socket.on('MyEvent', function (message) {
    $("#test").html(message);
  })
```

It is sending the data, but it is not refreshing when new data is available.
GetData.RData.R is being populated by an ajax call that is executed every 1 second to retrieve new data from a device.
If I manually refreh with F5 new data is displayed.

Comment: `setTimeout` fires once. You'll want to use `setInterval`, but you also need to `clearInterval` when the socket emits a `disconnect` event